# Opening an application from service linux c++

Tags: c++, linux, macos

I want to open an application A from another application B. By opening it, I don't want to open it within B. I found many ways to call an application from within another. However, what I want to do is open the other one(A) simultaeneously. How can I achieve this? fork() and exec() seem to open A within B. I am developing a code for Linux and Mac. Advice would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: If you want to run them from a command prompt, just write `./A& ./B&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In process A (the parent) call `fork()` to create process A and B (the child)

In process A wait for B to exit...

In process B, call fork() again (creating B and C) and exit

This causes A to collect the status code of B and prevent it becoming a zombie.

B's exit causes C to be orphaned, becoming owned by `init` and thus it's no longer a descendant of A.

in process C, call `exec` to replace the program in the current process with the one you want.

something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

void forkBtoC()
{
    cout << "B forking" << endl;
    auto child = fork();
    if (0 == child) {
        cout << "C execing" << endl;
        execl("your-program-here", "arg1", "arg2", nullptr);
    }
    else {
    }
}

int main()
{
    // I am parent A
    cout << "A forking" << endl;
    auto result = fork();
    if (result == 0) {
        setsid();
        forkBtoC();
        // I am child B
    }
    else if (result > 0) {
        // I am parent A. result is the pid of B
        int B_code = 0;
        waitpid(result, &B_code, 0);
        cout << "B returned " << B_code << endl;
    }
    else {
        assert(!"failed to fork A");
    }

    return 0;
}
```